# requirejs duplicate paths entries not working

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have following code as sample to research a problem. In this code "js1 and js2 loaded" never gets called, and no errors. I have tried to debug to log any errors from requirejs, but could not find the root cause.

```
         require.config({
            paths: {
                jQuery : "jquery",
                underScore : "underscore-min",
                backBone : "backbone-min",
                js1 : "js",
                js2: "js"
            },
            shim: {
                'jQuery': {
                    exports: '$'
                },
                'underScore': {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                'backBone': {
                    deps: ['underScore', 'jQuery'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                }
            },
            waitSeconds: 0
        });

    require(["jQuery"], function(){
            require(["underScore"], function(){
                require(["backBone"], function(){
                        require(["js1","js2"], function(){
                            console.log('js1 and js2 loaded');

                        });

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: If I change waitSeconds to 10, I get Error: Load timeout for modules: js2

Comment: What is `js` in your filesystem, a directory? Or is there a `js.js` file you're trying to load?

Comment: its a file js.js, that has just a console.log("JS loaded");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting any errors because you've set `waitSeconds: 0`, which disables RequireJS' timeout. See the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds).

Using `paths` for this won't work. To be able to load the same actual module under two different names you need to use [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map):

```
map: {
    "*": {
        js2: "js1"
    }
}
```

Note that this does not create two *instances* of the module. If you compare the module objects you get when you require `js1` and `js2` you'll see they are the same object. If what you want to do is get multiple instances of an object, you should design your code for such usage.

Comment: If I change waitSeconds to 10, I get Error: Load timeout for modules: js2